# LINQ join on two or more conditions

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying to create a linq join statement which joins an object from a table based on two conditions

```
MESSAGES
======
ID (int)
UserID (Guid)

MESSAGEPART
======
MessageID (int) 
IsPlaintext (bool)
MessageContent (nvarchar(max))
```

Here's the query I want to write, essentially:

```
var messages = from m in db.Message 
               join p in db.MessagePart on m.ID equals p.MessageID 
                                        and p.IsPlaintext equals false
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. This is the best I can do.

```
var messages = from m in db.Message 
               join p in
               (from x in db.MessagePart where x.IsPlaintext == false select x) 
               on m.ID equals p.MessageID
```

This seems a bit longwinded. Is there a more elegant way of achieving it?

Comment: Can you just make the second `join` condition a `where` instead?

Comment: What exactly is long winded about it? Is there a specific part of the code you don't like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An elegant solution.

```
  var messages = from m in db.Message 
                   join p in db.MessagePart on m.ID equals p.MessageID 
                   where p.IsPlaintext == false
```

Comment: +1 this because it is as OP asked "elegant" and will also generate nice SQL

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

```
var messages = from m in db.Message 
               join p in db.MessagePart 
               on new { m.ID, false } equals { p.MessageID, p.IsPlaintext }
```

or you could try this one:

```
var messages = db.Message.Join(db.MessagePart.Where(x=>x.IsPlainText==false),
                               x=>x.ID,
                               y=>y.Id,
                               (x,y)=>new {});
```

Inside the `new { }` you will declare the properties of the anonymous type you select.

ps. If you update your post and show there which fields you want to select, I could update also mine.

Comment: I like like your first answer because it solves a problem I was having the other day, but I think the SQL it would generate would be nasty as..